# Proof verification: if $(x_n)\to x$ and $\forall n\in\mathbf{N}(x_n\ge 0)$, then $(\sqrt{x_n})\to\sqrt{x}$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Is the following argument correct?

**Proposition**. If $(x_n)\to x$ and $\forall n\in\mathbf{N}(x_n\ge 0)$, show that $(\sqrt{x_n})\to\sqrt{x}$.

*Proof.*  Assume $x\neq 0$. Now since $x_n\ge 0,\forall n\in\mathbf{N}$, appealing to theorem $\textbf{2.3.4}$, yields $x\ge 0$ but $x\neq 0$ and so $x>0$ and by extension $\sqrt{x}>0$.

Let $\epsilon>0$. Since $(x_n)\to x$, there exists an $N\in\mathbf{N}$ such that $|x_n-x|<\sqrt{x}\epsilon$ whenever $n\ge N$. In addition since $x_n\ge 0$ it follows that $\sqrt{x}\ge 0$ and thus $|\sqrt{x_n}+\sqrt{x}| = \sqrt{x_n}+x$. Now consider the following observation.
$$|\sqrt{x_n}-\sqrt{x}| = \frac{|\sqrt{x_n}-\sqrt{x}|\cdot|\sqrt{x_n}+\sqrt{x}|}{|\sqrt{x_n}+\sqrt{x}|} = \frac{|x_n-x|}{\sqrt{x_n}+\sqrt{x}}\leq \frac{|x_n-x|}{\sqrt{x}}$$
Now let $n$ be an arbitrary positive integer such that $n\ge N$, we have $|x_n-x|<\sqrt{x}\epsilon$, consequently 
$|x_n-x|/\sqrt{x}<\epsilon$

$\blacksquare$

**Note**:

- In the above proof the assumption of $x\neq 0$ is due to the fact that i have proved the proposition in the event $x=0$.
- In addition theorem $\textbf{2.3.4}$ is the statement that if $(x_n)\to x$ then $\forall n\in\mathbf{N}(x_n\ge 0)$ implies  $x\ge 0$.

Comment: Some observations: (i) Second paragraph of proof, do you mean “whenever $n \geq N$” not “$x \geq N$”? (ii) Where do
we see that $x_n \geq 0$ for all $n$? (iii) I do not understand the wording in your bullet 2, it looks like shorthand for something that could be more easily written out clearly.

Comment: My apologies let me make some corrections and yes i do mean $n\ge N$

Comment: @Michael Bullet $2$ states that if $(x_n)$ converges to $x$ then if $x_n\ge 0$ for all $n\in\mathbf{N}$ then the limit $x$  must also be greater than equal to $0$.

Comment: I see.  You fixed (i) and (ii) in my observations but for (ii) you added the text "$\forall n \in \mathbf{N}(x_n\geq 0)$" in the statement of the proposition, which I do not understand but now I infer from your comment means "$x_n \geq 0$ for all $n \in \mathbf{N}$." I would prefer the latter exposition as everyone can understand it.  Anyway, except for this stylistic issue, everything looks fine.  I just gave +1 for question.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for your help and apologies for the inconvenience.